# NodeJs - Alterar valor de um vetor em um if else

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando fazer uma função que possa retornar os valores caso estejam sendo passados pelos parametros ou pelo corpo de uma requisição, a solução que eu pensei foi essa:

```
function getReqInfo(req){
  let params = []
  if (Object.values(req.body)  ){ params = Object.values(req.body)   } else
  if (Object.values(req.params)){ params = Object.values(req.params) }

  return params;
}
```

Mas mesmo entrando em um dos escopos o valor da variavel params continua o mesmo, tentei dessa forma também:

```
function getReqInfo(req){
  let params = []
  if (Object.values(req.body)  ){ return Object.values(req.body)   } else
  if (Object.values(req.params)){ return Object.values(req.params) }

  // return params;
}
```

mas também não funcionou.

Eu já coloquei fiz esse teste:

```
function getReqInfo(req){
  let params = []
  if (Object.values(req.body)  ){ console.log('teste1')   } else
  if (Object.values(req.params)){ console.log('teste2') }

  return params;
}
```

E os `console.log`s exibem a mensagem normalmente, mas não estou conseguindo atribuir o valor de `Object.values(req.body)` ou `Object.values(req.params)` para a variavel `params` ou retorna-los

Comment: Mas qual erro é retornado, os valores da requisição não são strings?

Comment: @LeAndrade são jsons, eu converto os valores para vetores e preciso atribui-los a variavel params

Comment: Então man, tá bem difícil até de tentar simular o que pode estar acontecendo. Quando vc diz **Mas mesmo entrando em um dos escopos o valor da variavel params continua o mesmo**, o valor seria qual, vc tá conseguindo pegar os parâmetros da **url** e do **body** certinhos? Se der um console.log() neles o que é retornado?

Comment: É o seguinte: eu estou fazendo aquele esquema truthy e falsy para ver se o usuario está mandando a requisição no `req.params` ou no `req.body`. Se o `req.params` está nulo e o `req.body` está preenchido, a variavel `params` deveria assumir o valor do body e vice e versa, se eu mando um `console.log` dentro de cada um dos if's ele retorna o valor sem problemas, em qualquer um dos casos, o que indica que o if e o else estão funcionando, atribuir os valores à `params`  é o problema

Comment: Consumir os valores de Object.values sem saber as chaves parece-me perigoso. As chaves de objetos não têm de respeitar uma certa ordem, por isso teoricamente a array Object.values pode ter ordem diferente dos elementos.

Comment: Pelo que eu já tentei o Object.values sempre vem na mesma ordem que os objetos foram passados, se eles respeitam uma ordem padrão não tem nenhum problema, pelo menos não teve até agora...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

em javascript temos mais do que simplesmente valores true e false, temos truthy e falsy, quando você passa um json vazio para a função Object.values(), ela retorna um vetor, caso o json esteja vazio irá retornar um vetor vazio, e um vetor vazio é truty!!

[image: array vazio js]

Então toda vez que entrar nesse código ele irá entrar nesse primeiro if, mesmo sem nada no json (se for undefined no caso a função Object.values irá acionar uma exceção)
então a verificação correta que se deve fazer ao compara se há valores no json é:

```
if (Object.values(req.body).length > 0) { /* código */ }
```

desse jeito irá comprar o tamanho do vetor, se houver algum valor ele entrará no if.

Comment: Depois que eu li sua resposta com mais calma eu percebi que ela resolve meu problema, te interpretei mal, desculpe...

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está utilizando **else if** e não somente um else, como nas duas verificações (if) ele retorna false, a variável params não retorna nada, porque realmente não tem nada pra retornar.

Sugiro que remova os ifs e com **console.log** mesmo e verifique o que você está recebendo de retorno da função e utilize o `if else` para fazer as verificações, faça isso, se não, faça aquilo, ele só terá dois caminhos. OBS: Você tem que ter certeza que ele retornar somente esse dois caminhos mesmo, se não você vai ter um erro.

Comment: Então, existem momentos em que eu vou querer que ambas as condições sejam falsas e o vetor retorne vazio mesmo. Eu já coloquei um **console.log** nas duas, e ele entra no escopo normalmente, o problema é que eu não consigo atribuir o valor de **Object.values(req.body)** ou **Object.values(req.params)**  para a variável **params**

Comment: Não consegue por que? Ela sempre retorna vazio? params é um array, tenta dar um params.push(Object.values(req.body))

Comment: sim ele sempre retorna como um `[]` independente se qualquer das condições for verdadeira. Eu tentei usar o push como vc falou, não deu certo.